# Error loading Python lib while trying to open an exec file (OS X)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to convert a python script to exe using auto-py-to-exe. I had no errors whatsoever when building the exe, but when I try to open the app I get an error:

```
[63820] Error loading Python lib '/Users/calinap/output/random_movie_generator.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/calinap/output/random_movie_generator.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/calinap/output/random_movie_generator.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: code signature invalid for '/Users/calinap/output/random_movie_generator.app/Contents/MacOS/Python'
```

The script has some additional files: an xlsx and another py file that are in the correct directory.

If you know other ways to convert it or have a solution to my problem please help!!

Comment: Is there a way to make that possible?

Comment: @usr2564301, clearly, `random_movie_generator.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` is a macOS executable that, according to the error message ("code signature invalid"), is missing a signature

Comment: @summerbye, you can install Windows 10 for free and run auto-py-to-exe from there

Comment: @usr2564301 the exec file was opened on my Mac and also built for my computer. Firstly, I wanted to solve that problem, then maybe find a way to run it on a Windows